# Bind DataContext to Resource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to bind a DataContext to some element in my resources. The resources are embedded in a ContentControl that is created via a DataTemplate and has already a DataContext set. This DataContext has a StatusController (property name: Status) I want to attach to the StatusControllerViewModel that transforms the properties and events from the StatusController to View conform properties:

```
  <ContentControl.Resources>     
    <CSharp:StatusControllerViewModel DataContext="{Binding Status}" x:Key="StatusViewModel"/>
</ContentControl.Resources>
```

The problem is that this message shows up:

> Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for
>   target element

The StatusControllerViewModel is derived from DependencyObject and has a DependencyProperty named DataContext.

When deriving it from Freezable it works, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of your problem depends on WPF does not know what `FrameworkElement` to use to get the DataContext, because your `StatusControllerViewModel` does not belong to the visual or logical tree of the ContentControl (since it is a resource).

If you make the `StatusControllerViewModel` derive from `Freezable` - as you told - you solve your problem, since Freezable objects can inherit the DataContext even when they are not in the visual or logical tree.
Your can find a full explanation about Freezable DataContext inheritance [here](http://drwpf.com/blog/category/freezables/):

> Normally, [...] DataContext bindings are resolved based on the target
>   dependency object's position within the element tree (or the namescope
>   to which the target dependency object belongs).  But in this case, the
>   target dependency object is not actually in the tree.  Instead, it is
>   just a property value on another object.  That other object may or may
>   not be in the tree.
>
> The reason the Freezable trick works is because a Freezable object has
>   its own notion of “inheritance context”.  When the property engine
>   sets the effective value of a dependency property, it looks at that
>   new value to determine whether it is a dependency object that would
>   like to be part of a special inheritance tree.

I hope it can help you.